# XAMPP PHP not working after Ventura upgrade

Tags: php, xampp, macos-ventura

XAMPP 8.2.4, Mac OS 13.6.3 Ventura, NetBeans IDE 20

I have used XAMPP for many years on a Mac for html/php/mysql development. With an upgrade to Ventura, a test php NetBeans project cannot be found on Safari localhost. Html NetBeans projects display just fine on localhost.

Netbeans tries to run http://localhost/PhpProject2/index.php and Safari gives:

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Error 404

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by moving the existing projects to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs and updating the Project Properties Run Configuration to http://localhost/